# Custom collation to not differentiate between a solidus and backslash

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, constraints

I want to make a custom collation/constraint for a column in my database table, which will also have a unique constraint, such that it doesn't differentiate between between a solidus `/` and a backslash `\` i.e it will consider all of the following as the same thing:

```
\path\to\some\file
/path\to/some/file
```

So how can I achieve this through SQL and SQLAlchemy?

*PS: I am using sqlite3*

Comment: The problem is not unique to SQLAlchemy; once you have a collation / constraint worked out, a SQLAlchemy solution follows from that, but using SQLAlchemy does not put any restrictions on this problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to know how to achieve it first through pure SQL. And later through SQLAlchemy. And hence the Python and SQLAlchemy tag

Comment: Creating custom collations is not possible with "pure SQL"; you need to use the SQLite C API or whatever mechanism your database driver offers (SQLAlchemy has none).

Comment: @CL.: Ah, in which case the `python` tag would be applicable at least. :-)

Comment: @CL. no other workaround to achieve a similar thing?

Comment: You could do something horrendous like duplicate the data, with all \ replaced with / [in itself a horrible thing to do in SQL, but possible] and shove the constraint on that column.  

That a thing can be done purely in SQL probably doesn't mean it should.

Comment: @Nt let me add, is there an "elegant" workaround to achieve such a thing?